# Cross-browser Normalization

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, cross-browser

I have been googling and doing some research since 3 days to figure out (or make) cross-browser, css normalization file but I am not very close to that.

I know that there is "normalize.css" but this isn't fully effective. For example, you gotta set margins for ul li elements or line-height for the website to make it cross-browser and these are not even set in normalize.css, so this isn't fully cross-browser. Also, another problem is checkboxes or radio buttons are not aligned with labels.

It would be perfect to have css file that normalize all the html tags, like bootstrap does. But bootstrap uses classes for normalization, which is not what I need. I need something like foundation, it normalize html tags with applying css on html tags. So, for your projects you can create your own mixin, helper classes which won't collide with framework's.

So, is there any normalization file like that? I don't wanna use any framework because they are unnecessarily heavy.

Comment: did you tried https://modernizr.com/ ???

Comment: I did try classic h5bp and it has some problems too. for example, li element and its dot style icon does not have same padding between them. And, checkbox, radio buttons are not aligned with label. These are some I found.